# Invoke method in Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have a class with a method that I want to invoke using Roslyn.

The class is like this

```
public class StudentService
{   
    //consider this will get data from an external api using HttpClient
    public static List<Student> GetStudents()
    {
       return new List<Student>();
    }
}
```

Can you help me how could I call it like this:

`var result = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync("GetStudents()")`

Thanks in advance

Comment: where's your rosyln code?

Comment: You can't just do `GetStudents()` in C# (since it is instance method it requires an instance)... so why would you think it should be possible to do in some other way?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I edit the question

Comment: The idea behind @AlexeiLevenkov's comment still stands after your edit - your string should represent code that would compile were it written outside of this script.  I'm guessing you did not add `using static YourNamespace.StudentService;`, so try `var result = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync("StudentService.GetStudents()");`

Comment: Hi @xpoiled7, it would be great to help peope help you by posting your code. Displaying the errors you get would also be great. Otherwise we could just asume things and solve other problems :)